# Check if a file belongs to given folder or its subfolders - eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, directory, filepath, subdirectory

I am trying to make an eclipse plugin.I need to check if a given file belongs to a given folder or its sub folders. The path of folder is taken as input from user. The file may belong directly inside the folder or may be deep inside the subfolders. How can i achieve this checking? If it belongs to the folder/subfolders, then the entire file path is returned. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you asking about files in the workspace (using things like `IFile`) or just files in general.

Comment: @greg-449 : ya files in the workspace.eg :  the name of file input maybe HelloWorld.java . Am also given woth the project folder name,eg:SampleProj and path : H:\eclipse\workspace\Sample. I need to check if the HelloWorld.java belongs somewhere inside the SampleProj folder

Comment: There is no particularly clever way, you can use the `IResource.accept` method to call an `IResourceProxyVisitor` on everything in a container, or just recursively look at the container `members()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by recursively check if the file belongs to that folder . This is the code :`

```
    public static void checkDirectoryContents(File dir,String filename) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                checkDirectoryContents(file,filename);
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nFile name and path found" + file.getName() +" " +file.getCanonicalPath());

                if(file.getName().equals(filename)) {
                    System.out.println("\nFile name and path found !!!!!!!" + file.getName() +" " +file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The check does has sense if there can be ".." in the path of the root folder or subfolder. In this case getCanonicalPath() can help you which gets the corresponding full path having the ".." entries processed and removed from the result. E.g. such check should be used to prevent such problems like "zip slip".

```
File rootFolder = ...;
File subFolderOrFile = ...;
if (rootFolder.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(subFolderOrFile.getCanonicalPath()) {
    // subFolderOrFile is truely uder the rootFolder
}
```